# How to route back to producer

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a PoducerTemplate. With the template I want to send a message to a route. Within the route I want to process the message and then I want to get the result back.

The producer:

```
String response = producerTemplate.requestBody("direct:start", message, String.class);
```

The Route:

```
from("direct:start").process(...).to(?);
```

The question is, how should the route look like, to get the response after process?

Comment: Well you don't need to do anything. You should get the response back since it is a `direct` endpoint. What happens when you run it? Did you change the exchange pattern as mentioned to `InOut`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mindsets when thinking about getting the response from a route. One is the traditional [Request/Reply](http://camel.apache.org/request-reply.html) pattern. This would be most appropriate when the last step in the route also follows this pattern. The typical case would be a web service call or http request. We would expect these components to *return* something, and that would be the value returned by the `requestBody` method.

The other is to take a traditional one-way route and simply have the last `Out` message returned. This would be done by setting the [Exchange Pattern](http://camel.apache.org/exchange-pattern.html) to `InOut`. A common use case for this might be for confirmation that the data placed at the last step meets certain criteria, or perhaps for auditing purposes.